# Telegram bot api keyboard

Tags: python, tornado, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have problem with Telegram Bot Api and with "ReplyKeyboard". I'm using Python 2.7 and I send post request:

```
TelegramAPI.post(TELEGRAM_URL + "sendMessage", data=dict(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text="", keyboard={'keyboard': keyboard, 'one_time_keyboard': False, 'resize_keyboard': True})
```

keyboard in this format:

```
[["A button"], ["B button"]]
```

But in Telegram I don't see keyboard. What problem can be?

Comment: What wrapper are you using? Can you please share the doc for  `TelegramAPI`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Bot API documentations](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage), a custom keyboard requires a `reply_markup` parameter, whose value is a JSON-serialized specification of the keyboard. Assuming your `TelegramAPI.post()` function does not JSON-serialize for you, I would try the following:

```
import json

json_keyboard = json.dumps({'keyboard': [["A button"], ["B button"]], 
                            'one_time_keyboard': False, 
                            'resize_keyboard': True})

TelegramAPI.post(TELEGRAM_URL + "sendMessage", 
                 data=dict(chat_id=CHAT_ID, 
                           text="Has to be non-empty", 
                           reply_markup=json_keyboard))
```

Note that `text` has to be non-empty.